# Serilog: rolling log file per day, but also per application run?

Tags: logging, serilog

How can you configure Serilog to roll log files **per day**, but ***also*** have **a new log file on every** new application **run**? I didn't find a way for that, where my old log files would still be deleted.

If I would name my log file like:

```
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo );
....
.WriteTo.File( $@"logs\Info_{timestamp}.txt", retainedFileCountLimit: 90, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information, outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}]<{ThreadName}({ThreadId})> {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}" )
```

I will get a new log file per application run like:

Info_2018-05-15_07-42-09**20180515**.txt

Info_2018-05-15_07-42-39**20180515**.txt

But then **20180515** is added automatically *(I don't want)*,
because of rollingInterval: RollingInterval.**Day** *(I want)* and
later my log files will fall through the
automatic deletion process *(I would need)*, because of the:

```
DirectorySearchPattern = $"{_filenamePrefix}*{_filenameSuffix}";
```

in the ***PathRoller.cs*** of Serilog.Sinks.File

Comment: Essentially there's a need for a DSL to be added to `.File`s config mechanism; for now, as you've discerned, there's not many faciities (or complexity) in the implementation. Another example of something I wanted is to start at `file_000.log` not `file.log` - one can imagine many things people would like things in this space. It's a matter of finding a set of people to do a) spec work b) implementation of that once that's agreed

Comment: Just use RollingInterval.Infinite